# MySQL User ID 10-50 Update

Tags: mysql

Hi i have a lot of users with Different Locations in my table.

I will change the location of User id 10-50 to  same city , state and country id.

Can anybody help me with The SQL Statement ??

Thx

Comment: You haven't posted nearly enough information for anyone to help you. What have you tried? Add the SQL code for queries you've made, show the output, and explain how it's not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your table structure, but something like this should do the trick:

```
UPDATE `my_table`
SET `city` = 'new city',
`state` = 'new state',
`country` = 'new country'
WHERE `id` BETWEEN 10 and 50;
```